# Change / update / replace existing constraint

Tags: xamarin.ios, autolayout, constraints

I've added constraint programmatically like this

**TileJob.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(size_15_of_Parent).Active = true;**

But now, when screen rotates i need to change / edit / update this constraint. How can i achieve that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yes, It did ! Thanks for a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `NSLayoutConstraint` at first .

```
NSLayoutConstraint con = s.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(15);
con.Active = true;
```

#### change / edit / update

```
con.Constant = 20;
```